# identify objects with 2 classes using knn and greyscale and display the appearance in the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, image-processing, google-colaboratory, knn

The problem is with the GUI display and maybe the image processing in google colab module. I created a GUI display. If I upload an image/input image and click the identify button, the display output that will be identified is different from the output of the input image. For example, I input a picture of a class of cavities but the GUI output shows the class "symptoms of cavities" so it doesn't match the input results. and the results of the values from knn and grayscale do not match. if in image processing in colab the cavity class has a value of 0 and the cavity symptom class has a value of 1. help me

I am trying to make the input image display results that match the input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.